# Cannot invoke 'constraintsWithVisualFormat' with an argument list of type '(String, options: nil, metrics: nil, views: Dictionary<String, UIView!>)'

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, constraints

I wrote following code in my demo project.

```
func createConstraints() -> Void
    {
        //Views to add constraints to
        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("red",vwRed),("blue",vwBlue),("green",vwGreen))

        //Horizontal constraints
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[red]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

        //Vertical constraints
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[red]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
    }
```

where vwRed, vwBlue, vwGreen are defined as below

```
    var vwBlue:UIView!
    var vwRed:UIView!
    var vwGreen:UIView!
```

Now I am getting error as following

[image]

I'm using **Xcode 7-beta**.

Additionally, 
I also wants to mention that it was not accepting and giving error.

```
//Prep auto layout
vwRed.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
vwBlue.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
vwGreen.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
```

which I changed to

```
    //Prep auto layout        

    vwRed.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vwBlue.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    vwGreen.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I modified the code to the below and it got rid of the compiler errors.. does this work for you?

```
    func createConstraints() -> Void
    {
        //Views to add constraints to
        let views = Dictionary(dictionaryLiteral: ("red",vwRed),("blue",vwBlue),("green",vwGreen))

        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[red]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)

        //Vertical constraints
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[red]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)

    }
```